# Laravel get array of filenames from folder

Tags: laravel

I am getting an array of filenames from a folder like this...

```
$files = File::allFiles('myfolder/');
```

But the resulting array contains pathname as well.

Is there a way of just getting an array of filenames?  Or do I need to process each array item and extract the filename from it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an another way of getting file name:

```
public function index() {

    $filesInFolder = \File::files('folder');     
    foreach($filesInFolder as $path) { 
          $file = pathinfo($path);
          echo $file['filename'] ;
     } 
}
```

The pathinfo will gives you the output:

```
{ "dirname":"file_path", "basename":"file_name.file_extension", "extension":"file_extension", "filename":"file_name" }
```

Comment: Thanks, great alternative

Answer (score 3):

hope it helps:

```
public function parse() {
    $fileNames = [];
    $path = public_path('other');
    $files = \File::allFiles($path);

    foreach($files as $file) {
        array_push($fileNames, pathinfo($file)['filename']);
    }

    dd($fileNames);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the laravel Storage api:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

//...

$files = Storage::disk('diskName')->allFiles('folderName');
$fileNames = array_map(function($file){
    return basename($file); // remove the folder name
}, $files);
```